# How do I make sure CircleCi ignore a push to master caused by CircleCi itself?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, circleci

CircleCi runs when code is pushed to master, however CircleCi pushes to master itself in a run script called `Version Package Bump`. So after this first build, a second is run. But it fails with message:

> On branch master Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
>   nothing to commit, working directory clean Exited with code 1

How do I make sure CircleCi doesn't initiate again from a push caused by itself?

```
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:8.10.0
    branches:
      only:
        - master
    steps:
      - add_ssh_keys
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Keyscan DreamHost (HACK)
          command: ssh-keyscan -H HOST >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
      - run:
          name: Install Dependencies
          command: npm install
      - run:
          name: Build App
          command: npm run build
      - run:
          name: Verion Package Bump
          command: |
            git config user.name "circleci"
            git config user.email "EMAIL"
            git add .
            git commit -m "[ci] Generated Build"
            npm version patch -m "[ci] Bumped version number to %s"
            git push origin master
            git push --tags
      - deploy:
          name: Publish to DreamHost
          command: scp -r build/* HOST:./DIRECTORY/
```

Even if I wrap it in a conditional I still see that same error and a build happens twice:

```
if ! git diff-index --quiet HEAD --; then
    git config user.name "circleci"
    git config user.email "EMAIL"
    git add .
    git commit -m "[ci] Generated Build"
    npm version patch -m "[ci] Bumped version number to %s"
    git push origin master
    git push --tags
fi
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a `[ci skip]` or `[skip ci]` tag anywhere in a commit’s message.

See https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/skip-build/

Replace your

```
git commit -m "[ci] Generated Build"
```

with

```
git commit -m "[ci skip] Generated Build"
```

or

```
git commit -m "Generated Build [skip ci]"
```

Comment: That was it! Even though the docs say `This not only skips the marked commit, but also all other commits in the push.` I had to add `[skip ci]` to both commits. I'm assuming because `npm version` pushes a separate time.